# How to reuse a Test subspec with other subspecs of a podspec

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec, subspec

I have Pod named `PodABC` and it has multiple subspecs like `SubspecA`, `SubspecB` etc. There are corresponding test specs to the same like `TestSubspecA`, `TestSubspecB` etc. I want to have a common subspec(lets name it `CommonSubspec`) which will have all the mock, json files which needs to be used by test targets `TestSubspecA`, `TestSubspecB` etc.

If I am adding `CommonSubspec` as a dependency to `TestSubspecA` or `TestSubspecB` it throws the below error

`` ^[[A[!] `PodABC/TestSubspecA (0.0.1)` depends upon `PodABC/CommonSubspec (0.0.1)`, which is a `test` spec. ``

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem please?

Comment: Can you share your podspec file?